# Apache Tomcat run on port 80 on Mac Lion. It says the port are used?

Tags: tomcat, osx-lion, port-80

I need to have a homepage running on my Mac that external users can use. I thought the easiest way, was to make Apache Tomcat running on port 80. But when i try it says that the port are in use.

I can't see anything that are using port 80.

What to do???

Comment: Are you starting it up using " sudo catalina.sh start " ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Tomcat is listening on port 80, you need to start it up using sudo.  For example:  `sudo catalina.sh start`

(I already answered this in the comment above but figured I should submit an answer for completeness)

Answer (score 0):

OSX comes with a built-in Apache, which is probably enabled.

Got to "system preferences"->"sharing"->"file & web"->"Web sharing"

Make sure web sharing is disabled.

Comment: Web sharing are OFF.. THis does not support Java/JSP/Servlet so i need to make my own.

Comment: What's the output of this command "lsof -i :80"? It's possible you have to run this as root (sudo).

Comment: Code: (see the picture)
[link](http://i54.tinypic.com/w6z32u.jpg)